# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds980Library' > Failed to create parent directory when creating directory

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.2.3

I am using Android Studio 2.2.3. My app has always been compiling and working properly but suddenly today I received this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds980Library'.
> Failed to create parent directory 'C:\Users\[My path]\androidapp\build\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-ads' when creating directory 'C:\Users\[My path]\androidapp\build\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-ads\9.8.0'
```

I tried restarting Android Studio, using "File > Invalidate Caches / Restart...", and running Android Studio as an administrator, but the error persists. Any ideas about what may be the cause of this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was upgrading from Android 2.2.3 to Android 3.0.1. But then I was getting this error:

```
Warning:The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (23.0.1) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (26.0.2) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.0.1. Android SDK Build Tools 26.0.2 will be used. To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools. <a href="fix.build.tools.version">Update Build Tools version and sync project</a><br><a href="openFile:C:/Users/[My path]/androidapp/build/app/build.gradle">Open File</a>
```

The solution was commenting out `buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"`.